# iOS 7 modal view makes buttons grey (disabled)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm upgrading an app to iOS 7 and am running into a problem where all buttons turn to grey after I display a modal view. They're still clickable though. It only happens with modal views and not popovers.

[image: ios7 screen shot with blue buttons]

[image: ios7 screen shot displaying modal view]

[image: ios7 screen shot with grey buttons]

Comment: This is an Apple bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/16159798. Still not fixed in iOS8b4

Comment: On iOS9, still not fixed tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CarmeloS points out the tint color is most likely your problem. Look at UIAppearance and or another view/viewcontroller higher up in the view heirachy as I believe this is now an inherited trait. So you may have set it it elsewhere.

Comment: Yes the `tintColor` seems to be the problem. `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] tintColor]` before the modal view is `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0.478431 1 1` but after it's `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.392274 0.8`. Shouldn't the system change it back by itself? Oh well. I'll try to change it manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's the tintColor attribute, try setting `UIView.tintColor` Attribute explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal` for elements with tint color.

Answer (score -1):

For me, setting the `navigationBar`'s `tintAdjustmentMode` did the trick.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
```