# Why do my UIButtons change color in iOS 7 upon controller transition?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

So I have some UIButtons. They're blue when enabled, and gray when disabled, as I expect.

[image]

If I go from my front page to Current Contests and there's a network error like this:

[image]

I call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to get back to the main page, and I get this on iOS 7, iPhone 4:

[image]

Gray buttons, but they work. So I know they're not disabled. This does not happen on iOS 8, iPad Mini.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071512/ios7-tint-color-only-works-after-presenting-and-dismissing-another-viewcontrolle

Comment: which part, exactly? I'll write it up as an answer for anyone who comes later

Comment: self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal; Adding this in appdelegate didfinishlaunchingwithoptions fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using the `tintAdjustmentMode` property, introduced in iOS 7:

> When this property’s value is UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed, the
>   value of the tintColor property is modified to provide a dimmed
>   appearance.
>
> If the system cannot find a non-default value in the subview hierarchy
>   when you query this property, the value is
>   UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal.
>
> When this property’s value changes (either by the view’s value
>   changing or by one of its superview’s values changing), -the system
>   calls the tintColorDidChange method to allow the view to refresh its
>   rendering.
>
> *- from the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tintAdjustmentMode).*

When certain overlay views such as `UIAlertView`, etc., become visible, they essentially change this property to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed`. You can fix this by setting the `tintAdjustmentMode` for the entire `UIWindow` (and therefore subview hierarchy) with:

```
self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```